# How to use offline image atmosphere package (chrisben:imgcache) for meteor (1.6)

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I am trying to use offline image cache package (Visit https://atmospherejs.com/chrisben/imgcache) in my angular-meteor app. I have meteor 1.6 version in my app. When I have used this package I am getting below error.

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module imgCache due to:

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'imgCache' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.

I think this error comes because this package support CommonJS modules system and meteor 1.6 uses ES6 modules system. If I am correct then please help me how I can use this package in my app OR suggest me some other package for offline caching of images in my app.

Comment: Hi there, I personally wouldn't go that way, it is too risky due to multiple browser makes and versions. I see on github that the package has a number of issues and it smells like lifetime troubles. What I do is to keep my graphic assets in AWS S3, pipe them trough AWS Cloudfront for fast delivery and web caching at server end. I have a modified package of some Meteor S3 file upload which adds cache-control and expiry meta to the files. You can control how long you want to cache it and when you want the files to expire and eventually re-cache them.

Comment: If you want to go this way I can help you with all the necessary pieces. It is not a direct answer to your question, more of an alternative solutions suggested.

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks for you answer. I think it is a good alternative but I want some way to do this in my own server.